# How to retrieve specific data from firebase in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and nosql database

I am trying to retrieve some specific data from a Firebase. I have a node Drugs and Assaults and that node has many unique identifier as node which has so more data into it. I want to retrieve lat/lng from each node.

Please have a look at this.[Firebase database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKgrM.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the lat/lng, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference assaultRef = rootRef.child("Assault");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String latlng = ds.child("liststring").child("2").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", latlng);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
assaultRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

You output will be:

```
lat/lng: (20.330198..., 77.809580...)
lat/lng: (30.786742..., 62.664079...)
```

Comment: I think there is queries in firebase docs. Is it better to use them?

Comment: In this case, you don't need a `Query`. You need to use a queries in case of conditions. Does the code above work?

Comment: I am not the one who post the question. I just wondered why you did not use queries in your code.

Comment: I think your code will work, but if the datasnapshot is extremely large, then it will take a while to get the data. Am I right?

Comment: As i said, there is no need. You can use the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` directly on the reference.